# Why can't I customize my second UI from its XAML in WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to call second UI page in WPF.
but my second UI does not get any components I set up from its XAML.

I called the second UI page by this code at **MainWindow**

```
MainUI mainUI = new MainUI();
mainUI.Show();
this.Close();
```

and this is the code of MainUI.xaml file.

```
<Window x:Class="KBJ_Tetris.MainUI"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KBJ_Tetris"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Tetris" Height="400" Width="700" Background="Beige">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border >
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="10" Width="100"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

At the design tab of Visual Studio, I see this pic
[image]

I set up the Background color to Beige, and put a Border on it.
but somehow, I cannot see any of those effects when it actually performed.
[image]

It's supposed to be shown as the pic of design tab,
but only this large empty window..

**FYI, I can control the second ui at MainUI.cs file.**
but I want it to be possible at XAML as well.

Can anyone give me an advice?

Comment: It works for me did you save your `MainUI` page?

Comment: Is it opened as a second page? Still doesn't work for me as second UI...

Comment: Ya it opens the second page and closes the first one maybe you're calling the wrong page.

Comment: Damn... I can control the UI at the constructor of MainUI.cs. If i called wrong one, the secound UI couldn't be controlled at the Constructor as it's not performed...

Comment: do you mind to send me your project to kbj0109@gmail.com, so I can look at it?

Comment: All i did was create a new project and added two windows and called the second window from the first one like you did. Try creating a new project.

Comment: FYI, I'm working on .NET Framework 4.0, same for u?

Comment: I'm at .NET Framework 4.5.2

Comment: As you said, creating another project  showed me a proper one... what the...  All my Thnx to u.

Comment: You're welcome, happy I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the second UI didn't get any effect from its XAML was that I deleted the **InitializeComponent();** at the Constructor of MainUI at CS file.

Completely my bad.. my mistake.

Sorry, and Thanks for ur help CNuts :)